# Escape return value key in mapping function

Tags: vimscript, key-bindings

I want to create a function for a mapping. The key for the mapping is configured through a variable. How can I escape the key in the return statement so it works?
This works:

```
let g:some_key = "<Up>"
function! <SID>TestFun()
  " doing something
  return "\<Up>"
endfunction
noremap <expr> g:some_key <SID>TestFun()
```

But I want something likes this

```
let g:some_key = "<Up>"
function! <SID>TestFun()
  " doing something
  return "\".g:some_key
endfunction
noremap <expr> g:some_key <SID>TestFun()
```

Right now my solution was creating a new variable holding the escaped key like this

```
exec 'let s:escaped_key = "\'.g:some_key.'"'
```

but I'm there's a better way to do it.

EDIT: The method I'm looking for should also work for a function called using `<C-R>=<SID>SomeFunction()<CR>` in a `imap`

Comment: I don't know if it will work, but have you tried the `fnameescape()` function ? If I store "<Up>" inside the `g:some_key` variable then type : `echo fnameescape(g:some_key)`, the output is "\<Up>".

Comment: Didn't think about that! It works in the specific case I asked about, but I forgot to mention that I also need it to work for function called using `<C-R>=<SID>SomeFunction()<CR>` in `imap` (and in this case `fnameescape()` doesn't work. Edited the question accordingly. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> All problems in computer science can be solved by another level of
>   indirection except for the problem of too many layers of indirection.
>
> -Kevlin Henney

Use a `<Plug>` (or `<SID>`) mapping to `g:some_key`. Use this new mapping in your function instead of `g:some_key`.

```
let g:some_key = '<Up>'
execute 'nnoremap <Plug>(some-key) ' . g:some_key

function! s:TestFun()
  " doing something
  return "\<Plug>(some-key)"
endfunction
execute 'nmap <expr> ' . g:some_key . ' <SID>TestFun()'
```

There are a few things worth noting:

- Using `nmap` instead of `nnoremap` so that we can map `<Plug>`
- Using double quoted string and escaping the key notation. e.g. `"\<Plug>.."`
- You can use `<SID>` mapping instead and use `<script>` if you want to emulate `nnoremap`. See `:h <SID>` and `:h :map-script` for more information.

For more help see:

```
:h :execute
:h <Plug>
:h <SID>
:h :map-script
:h key-notation
:h expr-string
:h literal-string
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer, really informative. It helped me correct a good part of the current design of the script. But this approach still doesn't work for value returned by <C-R>= expression I have to call feedkeys("\<Plug>(some-key)") if I want it to work.

Comment: @EnricoGhirardi Using `<c-r>=` is a bit more tricky however you can use `eval()` to create a properly quoted string. e.g. `eval('"'.substitute(g:some_key, '<', '\\&', 'g').'"')`. I usually avoid `eval()` (`feedkeys()` too), so use at your own risk. If you are able, I would suggest you use an `<expr>` mapping instead of `<c-r>=` for your `imap`'s.